# Storing data on a Firebase Database by creating seperate instances for an object

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Login Activity. Here the user is prompted to enter his details and the data is sent to a firebase database.

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ET_fname;
    private EditText ET_lname;
    private EditText ET_NIC;
    private EditText ET_email;
    private EditText ET_mobile;
    private Button signup_button;
    private Firebase mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        signup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        ET_fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_fname);
        ET_lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_lname);
        ET_NIC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_NIC);
        ET_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_email);
        ET_mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_mobile);


        //Click Listener for button
        signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating firebase object
                Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<database name>.firebaseio.com");

                //Getting values to store
                String firstname = ET_fname.getText().toString().trim();
                String lastname = ET_lname.getText().toString().trim();
                String NIC = ET_NIC.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = ET_email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mobile = ET_mobile.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating Person object
                User user = new User(firstname, lastname, NIC, email, mobile);

                //Adding values
                user.setFirstname(firstname);
                user.setLastname(lastname);
                user.setNIC(NIC);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setMobile(mobile);

                //Storing values to firebase
                //ref.child("User").setValue(user);
                ref.child("Users").child("User").setValue(user);
            }
        });private EditText ET_fname;
    private EditText ET_lname;
    private EditText ET_NIC;
    private EditText ET_email;
    private EditText ET_mobile;
    private Button signup_button;
    private Firebase mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        signup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        ET_fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_fname);
        ET_lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_lname);
        ET_NIC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_NIC);
        ET_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_email);
        ET_mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_mobile);


        //Click Listener for button
        signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating firebase object
                Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<database name>.firebaseio.com");

                //Getting values to store
                String firstname = ET_fname.getText().toString().trim();
                String lastname = ET_lname.getText().toString().trim();
                String NIC = ET_NIC.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = ET_email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mobile = ET_mobile.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating Person object
                User user = new User(firstname, lastname, NIC, email, mobile);

                //Adding values
                user.setFirstname(firstname);
                user.setLastname(lastname);
                user.setNIC(NIC);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setMobile(mobile);

                //Storing values to firebase
                //ref.child("User").setValue(user);
                ref.child("Users").child("User").setValue(user);
            }
        });
```

This is my User Class

```
public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String NIC;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;



        public User(String firstname, String lastname, String NIC, String email, String mobile) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.NIC = NIC;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;

    }public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getNIC() {
        return NIC;
    }

    public void setNIC(String nic) {
        this.NIC = nic;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

The Login Activity is used to send the data in the text fields to a Firebase Database. And everytime I run the app, it replaces the user instance created.

I want to be able to create seperate instances for each user, by autogenerating a number or otherwise. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a user with this snippet:

```
//Creating Person object
User user = new User(firstname, lastname, NIC, email, mobile);

//Storing values to firebase
ref.child("Users").child("User").setValue(user);
```

With this you set the data at this location `/Users/User`. If you want to add the data to a new unique child under that location, you use the Firebase `push()` method:

```
//Storing values to firebase
ref.child("Users").child("User").push().setValue(user);
```

This will create a complex-looking key, called a push id. It has similar traits as the UUID that @NishantRoy uses in his answer, but has the additional benefit that they are chronologically ordered.

Note that this is covered in the [Saving Lists Of Data section of the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-push). I highly recommend that you spend some time in that documentation before continuing as it provides answer to many common questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could go about this:

**1. FIREBASE AUTHENTICATION - My Recommendation**

Firebase offers an [authentication service](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html) that generates a `uid` for every user created.

You can use this `uid` as the key to store your user data in, and even add user authentication to your app.

**2. Java's UUID method**

If you DO want to create your own ID within the app, you can use the `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` method.

Example from [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/uuid_randomuuid.htm):

```
import java.util.*;

public class UUIDDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // creating UUID      
   UUID uid = UUID.fromString("38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d");     

   // checking the value of random UUID
   System.out.println("Random UUID value: "+uid.randomUUID());    
   }    
}
```

prints out:

`Random UUID value: 046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91`

The consensus online seems to be that collisions are VERY low in this method, however, there is still a chance, so I'd recommend using Firebase's `uid` because they guarantee it will be unique.